# javafx - partialy editable tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I use the following code to have an editable table in my javafx code:

```
@FXML private TableView<Person> personTableGUI;
...

    PersonTableGUI.setEditable(true);

    ReadOnlyObjectProperty <Person> listener = ResourceTableGUI.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty();

    tableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

    personIdTableGUI.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());    
    personIdTableGUI.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
            ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setPersonId(t.getNewValue());

    personIdTableGUI.setCellValueFactory((cellData) -> cellData.getValue().personIdProperty());
    personNameTableGUI.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().personNameProperty());
```

I use the class Person:

```
public class Person{

    private StringProperty personId;
    private StringProperty personName;
```

I try to make the following: when the stringProperty personName is equal to "John" the relevant cell of the editable personIdTableGUI column to not be editable, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `TextFieldTableCell` in order to switch the editability when the item changes. So, for example:

```
personIdTableGUI.setCellFactory(col -> new TextFieldTableCell<Person, String>(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER) {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(name, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setEditable(false);
        } else {
            Person rowValue = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            setEditable( ! "John".equals(rowValue.getPersonName()) );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It works ! it needs just a small change instead of pretected void it should be public void, so:                                                                                public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty) {

Comment: @G.V. Ah, yes; the method is protected in `TableCell` but `TextFieldTableCell` widens access to public, for some reason. Thanks for pointing that out; I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work.... I had removed the     personIdTableGUI.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()); and inserted your code, so personsId were not editable depite the name. I reinserted the removed code keeping your code  and the editing is still possible ...

Comment: @G.V. Can you clarify which column you are talking about? The code in your question is a bit confusing. Which cells do you want editable under which conditions?

Comment: Ok, when there is a person with name "john" on personNameTableGui collumn then I want the cell personIdTableGUI column for this name to not be editable. All the other id that belong to different names i want to remain editable. Thank you !

Comment: I would like to learn more for this concepts could you please tell me a good book for reading?